# How do I "refresh" a question to return it to the top of the list?

Tags: discussion, bumping

After I make a substantial edit to a question, is there a way to "refresh" the question to make it appear at the top of the list in the list of Questions?

The problem is that if it remains at the bottom, there is a low chance that anybody will read it.

Sincere thanks for help!

Answer (score 5):

It already returns to the top of the list of [active](https://math.stackexchange.com/?tab=active) questions (which is the default question view).

Comment: Thanks! Somehow on my account the default view is "newest". I don't remember changing any settings.

Comment: @yoyo: if you clicked ¨newest¨ when viewing the page, it automatically gets ¨remembered¨ without you having to toggle a setting.